# Select Row with multiple max values

Tags: sql, sql-server, max

For each order number, I need to select the maximum record and then select the maximum number for each record.

[image: QueryResults]

I just want one row, which is shown.

[image: Results]

Here is my code so far, how could I select what I need?

```
SELECT number, record, order
FROM Table1
```

Answer (score 2):

If the Number is not always increasing and thus could have different MAx within each Record group, you have to do it in two steps i.e. first get MAX(Record) and then get MAX(Number).

```
SELECT T.[Order], Max(Number) AS MaxNumber, MaxRecord
FROM
(
    SELECT [Order], Max(Record) AS MaxRecord
    FROM Table1
    GROUP By [ORDER]
) T
INNER JOIN Table1 T1 ON T.[Order] = T1.[Order] AND T.MaxRecord = T1.Record
GROUP By [ORDER]
```

Comment: I added a 'from' to your SQL statement in an edit ;)  Otherwise good

Answer (score 0):

Order really isn't a good column name as it's a reserved word.

```
SELECT max(number), max(record), order
FROM Table1
group by order
```

This might not be right, I'll need some clarification.  Your question is a bit confusing...this will return the max number and record for each order number.  Were you looking for the max record in reference to the max number?  IE:

555 777 1

666 555 1

In this case, would you expect to see 666 777 1, or 555 777 1?

Comment: 555 777 1  is what I would expect to see

Comment: Heh, you should clarify these cases in your example. I'd go with @amit_g and his answer

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your table is called `Table1`, the following should give you what you are looking for:

```
SELECT  MAX(number),
        A.record,
        [order]
  FROM  Table1 A
    INNER JOIN (  SELECT  MAX(record) record
                    FROM  Table1) B ON A.record = b.record
  GROUP BY A.record, [order]
```

This will effectively find the maximum `record` and then return the maximum `number` for this `record`.

Comment: This will work if there is only one order...if there is multiple orders in table1, you will need to expand the join on clause to include order

Comment: @Twelfth Quite right, thanks for pointing that out.  However as the OP asked to select the maximum record followed by the maximum number, I didn't factor in the order as it seemed redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Hi this is the another way to do to get the result

```
select MAX(t.number),MAX(t.record),t.ORDERNo from @table t
INNER JOIN @table tt
ON tt.ORDERNo = t.ORDERNo
AND tt.Number = t.Number
AND t.Record = tt.Record
GROUP BY t.ORDERNo
```